# How to arrange php string more tidy?

Tags: php

Below are the code and output of my php:

Code:

```
$fMessage = $fMessage . "\n" . $fTable[$x][2] . ' x ' . $fRate[$x][1] . '% = ' . $fRate[$x+1][0];
```

Output :

```
5000 x 0% = 0 
15000 x 1% = 150
```

Is there any way to make the output arrange more tidy for example :

```
5000        x 0% = 0
15000       x 1% = 150
```

Using "\t" and space is not possible as my the first digit might contains more than 5 digit. Please let me know if you know the solution. Sorry for the bad English. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str_pad` function:

```
$fMessage .= "\n" 
   . str_pad($fTable[$x][2], 12, ' ') 
   . ' x ' . $fRate[$x][1] . '% = ' . $fRate[$x+1][0];
```

Indenting output on the website:

```
$fMessage .= "\n" 
   . str_pad($fTable[$x][2], 12, '@') 
   . ' x ' . $fRate[$x][1] . '% = ' . $fRate[$x+1][0];

$fMessage = str_replace('@', '&nbsp;', $fMessage);

echo '<code>', nl2br($fMessage), '</code>';
```

Comment: your answer make sense, but somehow the spacing doesn't working. If I replace ' ' to others like '\n' or '.' it work fine.

Comment: How do you output and see the result? And how `"\n"` instead `' '` can working fine? This is a line break. [fiddle](https://3v4l.org/0IRc9) with spaces here.

Comment: I run this php and display the result in my wordpress(website).

https://3v4l.org/KlM4o

Comment: Got it. Try this code: https://3v4l.org/JjBRt. The `<code>` tag is used for a monospaced font.

Comment: yes it works. Didn't think of using this method. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very nice function called [sprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php). It supports format strings.

```
$x1 = 5000; $x2 = 15000;
$y1 = 0;    $y2 = 1;
$z1 = 0;    $z2 = 150;

$format = "%-10s x %d%% = %d\n";
$message = '';
$message .= sprintf($format, $x1, $y1, $z1);
$message .= sprintf($format, $x2, $y2, $z2);
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work in my situation. user14717238 answer solve my problem. you can have a look ya. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you copy the code and run it, it will show exactly your output contained in `$message`. Sadly, you did not provide the array contents.